# Reference for Hilbert numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory, reference-request, math-history

I've been studying a little bit of number theory, and during such studies I came across this interesting reference to Hilbert numbers, that is, numbers of the form $4n +1$. My question is a purely historical one: since they are called Hilbert numbers, I presume that Hilbert was one of the first to characterize this number series. However, I haven't been able to track down in which work, specifically, Hilbert does this, nor what was his original interest in so doing. Does any have any clue about this?

Comment: No, not really. see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_number and http://oeis.org/A057948 It appears you should look at   
T. M. Apostol, Introduction to Analytic Number Theory. You could pull the same trick with numbers $3n+1$ and then call numbers "primes" if they are not divisible by anything smaller in the same sequence other than $1.$

Comment: I've already checked Apostol's book, but it does not give any reference. In fact, he doesn't even reference Hilbert by name. He just describes the system in question. For what it's worth, I've also checked Flannery and Flannery's book which is referenced in the Wikipedia article you mentioned, but they also don't give a specific reference.

Comment: Try contacting Flannery and Flannery directly about this. They named the sequence, and if their choice of name is not clear from the context where it is introduced (pg 35 of their book, is it?), they should be able to point you in the right direction. I expect the naming was chosen for reasons other than any specific work of Hilbert connected to these numbers.